# Characterization of faithfully flat homomorphisms

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A \to B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings. Why are the following conditions equivalent?

- $A \to B$ is faithfully flat.
- $A \to B$ is injective, flat and $B/A$ is a flat $A$-module.

This should be elementary, but at the moment I don't see how to prove it. I know the usual characterizations of faithfully flat homomorphisms (which can be found in Atiyah-Macdonald for example).

Comment: (From a geometric point of view, a morphism of schemes is faithfully flat if it is flat and surjective. An injective map of rings induces a dominant map on spectra, and a flat map (of finite type) is open, so it implies faithful flatness.)

Comment: @Watson I don't understand your comment. What about $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[1/n]$, which is flat, injective and of finite type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because $\rm A \to B$ is injective you have the following sequence $$ 0 \to \rm A \to B \to B/A \to 0.$$

Then because $\rm B/A$ is flat, we have for any $\rm A$-module $\rm M$, $$ 0 \to \rm  M \to B \otimes M \to B/A \otimes M \to 0.$$

Hence $ \rm B \otimes M =0 \Rightarrow M = 0$ and so $\rm A \to \rm B$ is faithfully flat.

That's one part.

Comment: Thanks. I still have no idea for the other direction.

Answer (score 9):

I seem to get old because I had already come across this result three years ago. It is Lemma 5.5. in Lurie's paper on [Tannaka duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412266). It even works in arbitrary tame abelian $\otimes$-categories.

Answer (score 2):

To go the other way, suppose $f\colon A\to B$ is faithfully flat. The map $f\otimes B\colon A\otimes_AB \to B\otimes_AB$ is injective since it has a section, namely the multiplication map from $B\otimes_AB\to B$ given by $b\otimes b'\mapsto bb'$. Which means it is injective. The original map must therefore be injective, since it is so after a faithfully flat base change.